# How to embed a language in ClojureScript and let the user play with it in the browser

Tags: clojurescript

I'm working on a language for beginners. It's a Lisp and is currently embedded in [PicoLisp](http://picolisp.com) (or PicoLisp implementations) and
I'm planning to write another implementation in Clojure/ClojureScript.

One of the main requirements is that users should be able to **tweak a program** and **execute it** in the browser with **no help from a server**.

I heard that ClojureScript can compile itself thanks to `cljs-bootstrap` (even partly is great!) and I was wondering how could I, given a simple textarea and an OK button, set up a machinery that would execute the textarea content as my language.

So:

- Where can I define my language? How can I architect this?
- Will it be possible to load my language only once, and let the programs of users be executed several times?

Answer (score 2):

Until very recently this was not possible. Right now there is some work that bootstraps ClojureScript (e.g. ClojureScript in ClojureScript). Check out [cljs-bootstrap](http://clojurescript.net/) for example.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of cljs-bootstrap (I said "ClojureScript can compile itself"), but don't know how to organize things. What's between the textarea and the execution of a program in my language?

Comment: see http://swannodette.github.io/2015/07/29/clojurescript-17/ and https://github.com/swannodette/cljs-bootstrap

Comment: Thanks @edbond, part of the answer was here: http://swannodette.github.io/2015/07/29/clojurescript-17/ but how to not re-eval the definitions of my language? Maybe compile it to JS?

Comment: Yes, if you don't want to live edit language - compile it.